# Getting distinct rows from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a select statement that generates the following output.
[image: Select query result]

If you look the output there are few rows that generates duplicate AdjusterIds.
What i need is to get the FIRST ROW ONLY for repeated ids along with other rows.

I tried several Group By, Distinct etc but no luck.

Please note that there are several columns that i just omitted for simplicity.

Comment: What is the first row? And what DB engine do you use?

Comment: Where is your query? This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself. @juergend that's SSMS.

Comment: And is this real user data? Please don't expose such.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. There is nothing special. Its a simple Select statement that generates the output like that. For ex. SELECT AdjusterId, UserId, CompId,... From XYZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdjusterIds
                                        ORDER BY AdjusterIds)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this solved by question. I don't know why people are in a hurry. One should completely understand the question and then comment on it.

Comment: Tim, is there a way to do this without `CTE` ? Btw, `FROM dbo.TableName  AS T`.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: yes, you can use a sub query, a cte just increases readability and maintainability. It also allows to modify it easily to remove duplicates.